# Triangular Numpy Slicing

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I wanna slice a 2D numpy array between 3 coordinates, for example, given this numpy,

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

and coordinates (1,1) (3,1) (3,5), I want this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]]
```

any tips and guide are very appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to generate all indices (`np.indices`, `np.meshgrid`), and then apply some function that calculates whether a specific pair is within the triangle.  The goal will be a boolean mask, or the equivalent `where` coordinates.

Comment: Maybe  you'll find this useful: [How do I check if a point is inside a triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248076/how-do-i-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-triangle-on-the-line-is-ok-too).

Comment: It's very likely that [`numpy.tril_indices_from`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices_from.html#numpy.tril_indices_from) is what you want.

Comment: @Kasramvd, The `np.tri...` functions expect a square array

Comment: @hpaulj ah! yeah didn't notice that. But It seems that it's still convertible to a lower-triangle problem. Maybe by doing it for a proper slice and them changing the indices respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The core function for the `np.tri...` family of functions is `np.tri`.

Looking at its code, we see that it does (for a square array):

```
In [36]: np.greater_equal.outer(np.arange(4),np.arange(+1, 4+1))
Out[36]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Playing around with that I can generate something closer to your example:

```
In [39]: np.greater_equal.outer(np.arange(4),.5*np.arange(+1, 8+1))
Out[39]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False]])
In [40]: _.astype(int)
Out[40]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Whether this is a useful approach depends on how general of a triangle you want.  The example is a variation on the traditional lower triangle.  But if the points were more general, say:

```
 (1,1), (3,2), (2,6)
```

you'd have to come up with a more sophisticated